# Should I have conda installed within each virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, conda, anaconda3

I just made a clean install of Anaconda3 (python 3.7) on Windows 7 and created several virtual environments.  Without trying, I created some confusion.

1. My first clone of the base clean install does *not* have conda in it, and does *not* have the base install in its PATH.  So the only way to run conda is to specify the full path to the base install.  Seems wrong.
2. My python 3.5 env created from a yml file has an older version of conda in it, and does not have the base env in its PATH. It runs the old version and warns me to update it.  Seems wrong too.
3. My most recent clone of base does not have conda it it, but it *does* have the base env in its path, so it runs the base conda.

Is the third case the way it should always be?

How can I fix case one and two?

Is there anything I should pay attention to next time to avoid case one and two?

Update:

1. The first case is not related to the environment itself but rather to the Start Menu shortcut that is created by conda during the cloning.  When I open a console in the base, then activate this environment, everything works fine.  I can live with that.
2. I created this yml file with the command: `conda env export -n base > file.yml` in my old python 3.5 installation. So the following conda-related items are included in the yml file:

   - anaconda-clean=1.1.0=py35_0
   - anaconda-client=1.7.2=py35_0
   - anaconda=custom=py35_0
   - anaconda-navigator=1.9.2=py35_0
   - conda=4.5.11=py35_0
   - conda-build=2.1.4=py35_0
   - conda-env=2.6.0=h36134e3_1
   - conda-verify=2.0.0=py35_0
   - nb_anacondacloud=1.2.0=py35_0
   - nb_conda=2.0.0=py35_0
   - nb_conda_kernels=2.0.0=py35_0

So then the open part of the question is: which of the conda-related items listed above should not be in the python 3.5 environment?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't log my steps precisely, and only noticed the discrepancy later, but I will try to add details later.  Thanks for letting me know the way things *should* be though.

Comment: no worries, I've definitely been in similar situations. I added my comment as an answer, so it's a bit more readable, but don't feel obliged to accept if you want to hold out for perhaps a more authoritative response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, scenario #3, that is, `conda` only in the **base** env, with the **base** `bin/` directory in `PATH` appears to be the standard configuration.

When I cloned my base, i.e.,

```
conda create -n base-clone --clone base
```

it warned me that the **conda** and **conda-env** packages would not be copied, which resulted in the configuration you have in case #3.

To fix case (2), it would probably suffice to remove **conda** and **conda-env** from the YAML, then recreate the env.

Not sure about case (1), though normally, the **base** `bin/` directory should be on `PATH` in most default installations, and activating another env (cloned or not) shouldn't affect that entry, but only prepend `envs/your-env/bin/` (higher prior) to `PATH`.

I suppose I should add the disclaimer that this is all from empirical experience/testing (with **conda v4.5.12** installed via Miniconda on MacOS 10.14), and not any direct knowledge of conda internals.